# charge given to parallel conducting plates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

Whenever a charge say $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ is given to identical conductors we have to assume that charge is given to their outer side and not inner side to calculate redistribution.

Why?
I tried to find redistribution by not following above statement and it's true that I'm not able to get right answer but i just don't why?

Answer (score 0):

Similar charges always want to get **as far away from each other as possible**, so they sit on the outer surface of the two conductors. Assuming both are positive it will look like this.

[image]

Say $Q_2$ is negative the respective charges will lie on the inner surfaces of the conductors as the **two opposite charges attract each other**. Like so,

[image]

These instances occur purely on the basics of laws of attraction and repulsion.

Comment: if Q2 is negetive will the Q1 and Q2 reside on inner surface ?

Comment: No, whatever the net sum of the two charges together (whether it's positive or negative), the net charge will sit on the outer surface.

Comment: i think u misread my question .If there is two conductors plates  placed parrallel and close to each other .Now there are 4 surfaces two facing parallel and two facing away .now if q1 and q2 charge is given they it will reside on facing away surfaces as repulsion happen(and then redistribution happen).if q2 is -ve will they reside on inner(facing parallel surface ) due to attraction or still reside on facing away surfaces

Comment: They should reside on the inner side, I will correct my answer.

Comment: can u please explain me why will.redistribution takes on inner surface in 1st case and outer surface in case 2

Comment: The two opposite charges attract each other so they want to get as close as possible to each so they sit on the surface closest to the other charge (the inner one). The two similar charges don't like each other so they want to get as far away from each other so they sit on the surfaces that are farther away from the other charges (the outer surface).